# with Rebus is it possible to get notified when it can't communicate on its transport?

Tags: c#, rebus

I'm using a Sql Transport and I'm wondering if I could get a notification somehow that it wasn't able to communicate with it's bus.

I have the scenario where I want to display a message to the user when communication on the bus isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there's no way for Rebus to know whether sending a message will be successful, other than actually trying and sending a message.

An endpoint that receives messages will periodically log warnings in its log if it loses its connection to the transport.

Comment: This is what I was seeing when I was looking through the exposed methods.  What I was doing before was using an exception handler to catch when the sending failed.